# Modify the javascript to load on window load

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a javascript on "Speech to text recognition".The script runs on click.But I want to run the script on window/page load.I am not actually a javascript guy.Would you please help me to modify the script?

**Extra**[not essential to answer]: additionally I would like to modify the html code into simple html code from the existing "Vuitify" format.Can you help?

**Note**:Here I've addded the "snippet" that only will work on 'Goggle Crome' browser.

```js
var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
        var recognition = SpeechRecognition ? new SpeechRecognition() : false;
        Vue.component('speech-to-text', {
        template: '\n    <v-card>\n    <v-card-text>\n      <v-layout row wrap justify-space-around>\n        <v-flex xs8 sm9 text-xs-center>\n          <p v-if="error" class="grey--text">{{error}}</p>\n          <p v-else class="mb-0">\n            <span v-if="sentences.length > 0" v-for="sentence in sentences">{{sentence}}. </span>\n            <span>{{runtimeTranscription}}</span>\n          </p>\n        </v-flex>\n        <v-flex xs2 sm1 text-xs-center>\n          <v-btn\n            dark\n            @click.stop="toggle ? endSpeechRecognition() : startSpeechRecognition()"\n            icon\n            :color="!toggle ? \'grey\' : (speaking ? \'red\' : \'red darken-3\')"\n            :class="{\'animated infinite pulse\': toggle}"\n          >\n            <v-icon>{{toggle ? \'mic_off\' : \'mic\'}}</v-icon>\n          </v-btn>\n        </v-flex>\n      </v-layout>\n    </v-card-text>\n  </v-card>\n  ',
                props: {
                lang: {
                type: String,
                        default: 'en-US' },
                        text: {
                        type: [String, null],
                                required: true } },
                data: function data() {
                return {
                error: false,
                        speaking: false,
                        toggle: false,
                        runtimeTranscription: '',
                        sentences: [] };
                },
                methods: {
                checkCompatibility: function checkCompatibility() {
                if (!recognition) {
                this.error = 'Speech Recognition is not available on this browser. Please use Chrome or Firefox';
                }
                },
                        endSpeechRecognition: function endSpeechRecognition() {
                        recognition.stop();
                                this.toggle = false;
                                this.$emit('speechend', {
                                sentences: this.sentences,
                                        text: this.sentences.join('. ') });
                        },
                        startSpeechRecognition: function startSpeechRecognition() {var _this = this;
                                if (!recognition) {
                        this.error = 'Speech Recognition is not available on this browser. Please use Chrome or Firefox';
                                return false;
                        }
                        this.toggle = true;
                                recognition.lang = this.lang;
                                recognition.interimResults = true;
                                recognition.addEventListener('speechstart', function (event) {
                                _this.speaking = true;
                                });
                                recognition.addEventListener('speechend', function (event) {
                                _this.speaking = false;
                                });
                                recognition.addEventListener('result', function (event) {
                                var text = Array.from(event.results).map(function (result) {return result[0]; }).map(function (result) {return result.transcript; }).join('');
                                        _this.runtimeTranscription = text;
                                });
                                recognition.addEventListener('end', function () {
                                if (_this.runtimeTranscription !== '') {
                                _this.sentences.push(_this.capitalizeFirstLetter(_this.runtimeTranscription));
                                        _this.$emit('update:text', '' + _this.text + _this.sentences.slice( - 1)[0] + '. ');
                                }
                                _this.runtimeTranscription = '';
                                        recognition.stop();
                                        if (_this.toggle) {
                                // keep it going.
                                recognition.start();
                                }
                                });
                                recognition.start();
                        },
                        capitalizeFirstLetter: function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
                        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
                        } },
                mounted: function mounted() {
                this.checkCompatibility();
                } });
        new Vue({
        el: '#app',
                data: function data() {
                return {
                text: '',
                        sentences: null };
                },
                methods: {
                speechEnd: function speechEnd(_ref) {var sentences = _ref.sentences, text = _ref.text;
                        console.log('text', text);
                        console.log('sentences', sentences);
                        this.sentences = sentences;
                } } });
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.17/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css'>
<div id="app">
                <v-app id="inspire">
                    <v-container fluid>
                        <v-layout row wrap justify-center class="mt-4">
                            <v-flex xs12 sm10 text-xs-center>
                                <v-text-field name="x"
                                              label="The text"
                                              v-model="text"
                                              textarea
                                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4 text-xs-center>
                                <speech-to-text :text.sync="text" @speechend="speechEnd"></speech-to-text>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 text-xs-center class="mt-4">
                                {{sentences}}
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-app>

            </div>

        
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.17/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Can't you use the load event? like this: 

   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      ... your code here or call to your function 
    }, true);

Comment: Actually I am so new in javascript.I am learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the JavaScript code into a function and call the wrapped function on body onload using `<body onload="wrappedFunction();">`

Make sure your scripts/dependencies are loaded before this. You can add the scripts in the `<head>`

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us? How is it not working? Any errors? Wrong output? You need to be as detailed as possible instead of just "I tried. Not working."

Comment: Actually I didn't understood what do you mean by "wrappedFunction()". Would you please edit the code for me? Thank You.

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the previous comment.I misunderstood.

Comment: @Ghost I meant, you can create a new function name wrappedFunction like
var wrappedFunction = function () {
...your code goes here
}

Now call this function here `<body onload="wrappedFunction();">`

Comment: Yeah..now I understood.And I did that something with window.onload=function(). But that didn;t work. Actually wrapping will only do call the whole script ;but that is done automatically by link on page load. Actually I want to execute the recognition just on page load instead of clicking.

Comment: This will execute on Onload as the function will be called on onLoad.
Did you verify that your JS dependencies were loaded before the function was called in the head tag?